# How to install Psycopg2 for python3 on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I have run `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` and the up-to-date pip.

But when I ran `pip install psycopg2`, I got this error:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.7.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/flint1025/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/flint1025/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/flint1025/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/flint1025/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/flint1025/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/flint1025/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/flint1025/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/flint1025/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.7.1.dist-info'
```

Then after searching, some solution indicates I should change the ownership of the directory. So I tried `chown -R flint1025:27 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.7.1.dist-info` but got this error:

```
chown: cannot access '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.7.1.dist-info': No such file or directory
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are not installing in `virtualenv`,so you have to use : `sudo pip install psycopg2`

> Installing package without using virtual environment you need `root`
>   permissions.